# Exportar consulta MySQL con php a Excel

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día,

Quisiera de su ayuda para poder solucionar estos dos errores cuando exporto una consulta MySql con PHP a Excel, adjunto los dos errores y el código PHP para que me puedan entender y ayudar.

Error 1: Quitar esta notificación de Excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error 2: Mostrar caracteres especiales como tilde y Ñ

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include "../../conexion.php";
    $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE estatus = 1  ORDER BY fechaCreacion DESC");
    mysqli_close($conection);

    $excel = "
            <table>
                <tr>
                <th >Fecha/Hora creación</th>
                <th>Numero de contrato </th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Persona jurídica a facturar</th>
                <th>Proyecto</th>
                <th>Objeto</th>
                <th>Monto del contrato sin IVA</th>
                <th>Fecha inicio</th>   
                <th>Fecha fin</th>
                <th>Creado Por</th>
                </tr>
            ";
                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {               
                    $excel = $excel. "
                        <tr>
                            <td>{$data['fechaCreacion']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['idContrato']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['cliente']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['personaJuridica']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['proyecto']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['objeto']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['monto']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['fechaInicio']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['fechaFin']}</td>
                            <td>{$data['usuario']}</td>
                        </tr>
                     ";
                }
            $excel= $excel. " </table>";    
            header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
            header("Content-type:   application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Contratos.xls"); 
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: private",false);
            echo $excel;
?>
```

Comment: Sin estar seguro de ello, veo un problema en tus MIME types, pero deberías revisar. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document

Comment: Como seguna opinion, veo que el filename no está con sus propias comillas -> filename='Contratos.xls'